# Create multiple directory via Puppet

Tags: puppet

How do I create multiple file via Puppet?

For example I can run:

```
touch abc{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} to create abc1,abc2,abc3....abc8
```

How do I run the same via Puppet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At its simplest, you can specify a list of files by passing an array to a file resource:

```
$numbered_files = ["/abc1", "/abc2", "/abc3"]
file { $numbered_files:
  ensure => file,
}
```

To automatically build an array of filenames with a certain prefix, then the `range` function from [stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib) can do this trivially:

```
$numbered_files = range("/abc1", "/abc8")
file { $numbered_files:
  ensure => file,
}
```